# Plotting confidence intervals of predictions from a Bayesian beta regression model

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, prediction, bayesian

I have the sample data and code below and would appreciate your help on how to plot credible intervals of predictions from a Bayesian beta regression model.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(zoib)

data("GasolineYield", package = "zoib")

re.md <- zoib(yield ~ temp | 1 | 1, data=GasolineYield, 
              joint = FALSE, random=1, EUID=GasolineYield$batch, 
              zero.inflation = FALSE, one.inflation = FALSE, 
              n.iter=3200, n.thin=15, n.burn=200)

pred <- pred.zoib(re.md, data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01)))

df <- data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01), 
                 yield = (pred$pred[[1]][, 201] + pred$pred[[2]][, 201])/2)

ggplotly( 
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data = GasolineYield, 
aes(x = temp, y = yield, fill = batch), 
size = 4, shape = 21) + 
xlim(100, 600) + 
geom_line(data = df, aes(y = yield, x = temp), col="red") + 
theme_classic())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have little experience with Bayesian statistics (though I am keen to get into it), but I believe this is what you are after:

```
df1 <- data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01), 
                  pred$summary)
ggplotly( 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = GasolineYield, 
               aes(x = temp, y = yield, fill = batch), 
               size = 4, shape = 21) + 
    xlim(100, 600) + 
    geom_line(data = df1, aes(y = mean, x = temp), col="red") + 
    geom_ribbon(data = df1, aes(ymin= X2.5., ymax = X97.5., x = temp), alpha = 0.3) +
    theme_classic())
```

[image]

From the help of `?pred.zoib`:

> summary    if TRUE (the default), a basic summary on each posterior
>   predictive value, including mean, SD, min, max, med, 2.5% and 97.5%
>   quantiles, are provided.

this is a little bit different then what you are plotting since the mean in summary is in fact:

`rowSums(pred$pred[[1]])/ncol(pred$pred[[1]]`

To visualize the difference:

```
df <- data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01), 
                 yield = (pred$pred[[1]][, 201] + pred$pred[[2]][, 201])/2)

ggplotly( 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = GasolineYield, 
               aes(x = temp, y = yield, fill = batch), 
               size = 4, shape = 21) + 
    xlim(100, 600) + 
    geom_line(data = df1, aes(y = mean, x = temp), col="red") + 
    geom_ribbon(data = df1, aes(ymin= X2.5., ymax = X97.5., x = temp), alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = df, aes(y = yield, x = temp), col="blue") + 
    theme_classic())
```

[image]

Some additional considerations:

```
all.equal(rowSums(pred$pred[[1]])/ncol(pred$pred[[1]]), df1$mean)
#output
TRUE

all.equal(apply(pred$pred[[1]], 1, quantile, probs = 0.025), df1$X2.5.)
#output
TRUE

all.equal(apply(pred$pred[[1]], 1, quantile, probs = 0.975), df1$X97.5.)
#output
TRUE
```

same goes for `max`, `min` etc.

I am not sure what `pred$pred[[2]]` represents but you can generate a summary for it using the above approach and plot it like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01), 
              mean = apply(pred$pred[[2]], 1, mean),
              X97.5. = apply(pred$pred[[2]], 1, quantile, probs = 0.975),
              X2.5. = apply(pred$pred[[2]], 1, quantile, probs = 0.025))
```

lets plot both (be careful my R became non responsive for a bit when doing this with ggplotly):

```
  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = GasolineYield, 
               aes(x = temp, y = yield, fill = batch), 
               size = 4, shape = 21) + 
    xlim(100, 600) + 
    geom_line(data = df1, aes(y = mean, x = temp), col="red") + 
    geom_ribbon(data = df1, aes(ymin= X2.5., ymax = X97.5., x = temp), alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = df2, aes(y = mean, x = temp), col="blue") + 
    geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(ymin= X2.5., ymax = X97.5., x = temp), alpha = 0.3)+
    theme_classic()
```

[image]